# Batch script to move all *.doc and *.docx files to a new folder, while keeping subdirectory structure, when there are PDF files of the same name

Tags: batch-file, file-transfer, file-management, file-monitoring

I have thousands of word document files, both old and new formats, in a folder with multiple levels of subdirectories.  Many of them have been converted to PDF files but I need to keep the original Word documents.  I need to create a new folder somewhere that only contains the word documents that have PDF versions, and I must maintain the directory structure with sub folder structure intact.

To really make it complicated, as a bonus, I may need to sync the directory structure of of both the new directory with the word files, and the old directory with just the PDF files.  E.g, after moving the word documents, in the future, if a sub folder containing the PDF file gets re-named, I would need to match the word documents that have the same PDF names, and if the sub directory folder name doesn’t match, rename the folder containing the word documents to the folder contains the PDF files of the same name.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Super User. Do you have a batch script that you have already started with, you just don't know how to finish? We can't really help you out if you don't tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: No problem, I will go ahead and see what I can get done first and post it here!  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Robocopy which comes as a part of windows. From a CMD window run `Robocopy.exe /???`